# python error invalid syntax on if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I want to check if the variable `start_time` is less than, equal or greater than the `current_time` to compare for the time.

Here is the code:

```
start_date = str(stop_date[0])
stop_date = str(stop_date[1])
get_current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
get_start_time = time.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
start_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_start_time)
get_stop_time = time.strptime(stop_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
stop_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', get_stop_time)
current_time = str(get_current_time)

if start_time <> current_time <> stop_time:
   print "program is half way"
```

Here is the output for the `start_time`:

```
19:00
19:00
19:00
19:00
19:00
19:00
19:00
```

Here is the output for the `current_time`:

```
00:10:36 T:5304  NOTICE: 00:09
```

Here is the output for the `stop_time`:

```
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 19:30
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 20:00
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 19:30
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 20:00
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 20:00
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 19:30
00:09:33 T:6824  NOTICE: 20:00
```

When I try this:

```
if start_time <=> current_time < stop_time:
   print "program has finished"
```

It will give me an error: `invalid syntax`

It won't let me to have the `=` in the statement, I can only write on the statement with less than or greater than but not with the `=`.

How I can include the equal `=` with less than and greater than for the `start_time` to compare the time with `current_time`?

**EDIT: Opps, sorry my mistake. I pasted the wrong code so here is what I am trying to do:**

```
if start_time <=> current_time < stop_time:
    print "program is half way"
```

Comment: Well, there you go. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: Um.. wait: you want to check if it's less than or greater than or equal to? Won't this be *always true* no matter what?

Comment: @wil93 yeah that is what i am trying to do. So what I should use then?

Comment: @David isnt that always true? why the check then?

Comment: What? Are you sure that's what you want to do? The result is *always* true, as I said, so you would not need to even check it.

Comment: To clarify: can you make an example of some dates which would *fail* your check?

Comment: @wil93 yes, that is what i want to do. I want to compare the `start_time` with `current_time` to see if the time is equal, less than or greater than and also I want to check if it is less than the `stop_time`. How i can do that?

Comment: @wil93 should I use something like this `if start_time =! current_time < stop_time:`?

Comment: Then you actually just want to check if it's less than `stop_time`

Comment: You should do `if current_time < stop_time`

Comment: @wil93 what about I want to check `start_time` with `current_time`? i want to check with my current time to see if the current time is equal or not.

Comment: @David do you mean this : "current_time" is not equal to the "start time" and the "current time" < "stop time"?

Comment: @astrosyam yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to check that both of these hold:

1. `current_time` is either less than, greater than, or equal to `start_time`.
2. `current_time` is less than `stop_time`.

Now, the first one can be written like this:

```
if current_time < start_time or current_time > start_time or current_time == start_time:
   print "program has finished"
```

However, this is always true because `start_time` and `current_time` will either be equal (making `current_time == start_time` true) or different (making `current_time < start_time or current_time > start_time` true).

The second one can be written like this:

```
if current_time < stop_time:
   print "program has finished"
```

So, since the first one is not needed, you just need:

```
if current_time < stop_time:
   print "program has finished"
```

Comment: ooops sorry i pasted the wrong code in my question. Can you please change your code as I want to check `start_time` with `current_time` to see if it is less than, equal or greater than and also check with `stop_time` to see if it is less than `current_time`?  please see in my update question

Comment: The only difference is that now you want `stop_time` to be less than `current_time` (not the other way around), am I correct?

Comment: In the updated question you still say that `current_time` should be less than `stop_time`, so the present answer should be still correct.

Comment: yes that is correct. I tried to use the code on the update answer but it say the program are half way through which it is not. Any idea?

Comment: Uh? I've never seen such an error. Can you paste the complete error message?

Comment: there is no error, it just wont get past on the statement, but i found this is the correct one `if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time or current_time == start_time and current_time < stop_time:`. I will mark your answers as the answer.

Comment: @David you *really* didn't understand the central part of wils93's answer: `if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time or current_time == start_time` <-- **that check is nonsensical because it will always be true**.

Comment: Notice also that if you don't wrap that using parentheses you will have another surprise. `and` has precedence over `or` so this will happen:

`if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time or current_time == start_time and current_time < stop_time:`
==>
`if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time or (current_time == start_time and current_time < stop_time):`
==>
`if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time or False:`
==>
`if start_time < current_time or current_time > start_time:`